# Python 2.7.7/Pygame - How to detect if the mouse is within a circle?

Tags: python, pygame

Hi I am trying to make a punny cookie clicker type game called py clicker and made an invisible circle over the sprite which is a pie. How do I detect if the mouse is within the circle so when the user clicks it checks if it is in the circle and adds one to the counter?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the `x,y` of the center of the circle and it's `radius` then you can calculate the distance from the center of the circle to your mouse pointer when you click. If it's greater than the radius then you are outside. There is a built in method that might help called [math.hypot](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html%23math.hypot) that will return the length between two points.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [pygame.sprite.collide_circle()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle) . But you will need another `Sprite` with small `radius` and `mouse` position.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the graphics library and use the method called getMouse.